# Flexslider: turn off navaigation arrows

Tags: javascript, html, flexslider

Is it possible to turn off displaying navigation arrows in flexslider, when number of slides <= number of visible slides?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a whole page with all the options at http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/
As far as I can tell it already does it.
Check this fiddle, resize the page to see it add and remove the navigation depending on the page width.
http://jsfiddle.net/MAk4e/

```
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    animationLoop: false,
    itemWidth: 210,
    itemMargin: 5,
    minItems: 2,
    maxItems: 4                         
});
```

There are a heap of demos at:
http://flexslider.woothemes.com/index.html

Comment: Can you please check these website: sodispar[dot]com On bottom there are three sliders and first and second has navigation arrows. It is generated automatically, and I don't know how to remove arrows from these slider (where navigation is useless).

Comment: It seems you are using a wordpress plugin. I can not help you with that.

Comment: I'm not using plugin for this. Js script is in custom.js. Help me please.

Comment: put what you have now into a jsfiddle and I may be able to help